# SetText method can't find variable name for JTextField

Tags: java, swing

When trying to apply the setText() method within the ClearButtonHandler class in a simple java GUI program, the method can't find the variable name for the JTextField. The intent is for the text to be cleared when a user selects the clear button. "cannot find symbol, variable name fNameInput" and for each variable I am attempting to use the method for.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 *
 * @author joel.ramsey
 */
public class JRStarPhase5 extends JFrame{

    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {


    JFrame window = new JRStarPhase5();

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

    }//end main method

    //constructor for JFrame
    public JRStarPhase5(){
        setTitle("JRStar Star Gaze Order Processing");
        setSize (800,800);  
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0,2);
        pane.setLayout(grid);

        JLabel fNameLabel = new JLabel ("First name:");
        JLabel mi = new JLabel ("Middle initial:");
        JLabel lNameLabel = new JLabel ("Last name:");
        JLabel productChoice = new JLabel ("Star Gaze version:");
        JLabel licenseQuantity = new JLabel ("License quantity:");
        JLabel streetAddress = new JLabel ("Street address:");
        JLabel city = new JLabel ("City:");
        JLabel state = new JLabel ("State abbrev:");
        JLabel zip = new JLabel ("Zip code:");
        JLabel phone = new JLabel ("Phone Number:");
        JTextField fNameInput = new JTextField (15);
        JTextField miInput = new JTextField (1);
        JTextField lNameInput = new JTextField (15);
        JTextField productChoiceInput = new JTextField (1);
        JTextField licenseQuantityInput = new JTextField (2);
        JTextField streetAddressInput = new JTextField (20);
        JTextField cityInput = new JTextField (20);
        JTextField stateInput = new JTextField (2);
        JTextField zipInput = new JTextField (5);
        JTextField phoneInput = new JTextField (10);

        //add as last buttons
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
        SubmitButtonHandler sbh = new SubmitButtonHandler();
        submit.addActionListener(sbh);

        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
        ClearButtonHandler cbh = new ClearButtonHandler();
        clear.addActionListener(cbh);

        pane.add(fNameLabel);
        pane.add(fNameInput);
        pane.add(mi);
        pane.add(miInput);
        pane.add(lNameLabel);
        pane.add(lNameInput);
        pane.add(productChoice);
        pane.add(productChoiceInput);
        pane.add(licenseQuantity);
        pane.add(licenseQuantityInput);
        pane.add(streetAddress);
        pane.add(streetAddressInput);
        pane.add(city);
        pane.add(cityInput);
        pane.add(state);
        pane.add(stateInput);
        pane.add(zip);
        pane.add(zipInput);
        pane.add(phone);
        pane.add(phoneInput);

        //add last
        pane.add(submit);
        pane.add(clear);

    }//end constructor

    private class SubmitButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your order has been submitted!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }//end submit

    private class ClearButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            fNameInput.setText("");  
            miInput.setText("");
            lNameInput.setText("");
            streetAddressInput.setText("");

       }

    }//end clear

}//end main class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is, that you your variables are out of scope.
You define your `TextField`'s in your constructor and after the constructor you lose the reference to this variables.
Try an define them as fields.

```
public class JRStarPhase5 extends JFrame{
     public TextFild name1, name2, name3,... ;
     ...
     public JRStarPhase5(){
         this.name1 = new TextField("...");
         //and so on..
```

now you could use them in your code below.

See also [Fields in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is scope. The `ClearButtonHandler` class cannot find JtextField because of the scope in which you have defined.

The scope for JtextFields are JRStarPhase5 constructor. They are not visible outside it.
Define the JTextFields as instance variables (outside) the JRStarPhase5 constructor and instantiate inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JTextField` variables are not visible within scope of `ClearButtonHandler`. To fix, declare the variables within the scope of the `JRStarPhase5`class

```
public class JRStarPhase5 extends JFrame {

   JTextField fNameInput;
   ...
```

Also remove the `JTextField` initial keyword in the constructor of `JRStarPhase5` to avoid [shadowing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

```
fNameInput = new JTextField (15);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`fNameInput` has local context only to the constructor `JRStarPhase5` where it is declared.

If you want to access the components outside of the constructor, you should declare them as instance fields...

For example

```
public class JRStarPhase5 extends JFrame{

    /*...*/

    private JTextField fNameInput;

    /*...*/

    public JRStarPhase5(){
        /*...*/
        fNameInput = new JTextField (15);
```

You may want to take a look at [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Make all fields and labels public inside the class and then initialize them in constructor.